# Horner's rule in C

Tags: c

So I am writing a program that calculates the polynominals using the Horner's rule.

But after I enter the first coefficient the program crashes. What did I do wrong? I can't find the error.

EDIT: I just noticed that I was reading in the arguments backwards.

```
int main() {

    int degree;
    float x;
    float px = 0;
    float p = 0;
    float *a;
    int i;

    a = malloc((degree+1)*sizeof(float));

    printf("Enter the degree:");
    scanf("%d", &degree);
    printf("Enter the argument:");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    for (i = 0; i < degree+1; i++)
    {
    printf("Enter the coefficient Nr%d:", i+1);
    scanf("%f", *(a+i));
    }   
    for (i = degree; i > -1; i--)
    {
    p = *(a+i) * pow(x, i);
    px + p;
    }

    printf("%f", px);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `px + p;` assign to where?

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to allocate `a` after you input `degree`?

Comment: `p = *(a+i) * pow(x, i);` is not Horner's method, and you meant `px += …`

Comment: There is at least one of your previous question that you would not have had to ask if you used a proper compiler's warnings. The program in this question contains at least three issues that would be detected by a proper compiler. When are you going to use a proper compiler with activated warnings?

Comment: @ᴍaroun ᴍaroun changed it to px = px + p.                                 I was not aware that there was an issue with my compiler. What compiler would you recommend?

Comment: @user3004619 I am very satisfied with `gcc -Wall` and you may also like `clang -Wall`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you allocate memory for `a`, `degree` is yet to be initialized.

Also, remove the asterisk from `scanf("%f", *(a+i));`. You want the *address* of `a[i]`, not its *value*.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `a = malloc((degree+1)*sizeof(float));` you are using the value of `degree` without initializing it. An initialized variable can contain **ANY** value, most likely to be invalid and will take you to the scenario called **undefined behavior**. That's why the crash is there.

Second thing, every time after a `malloc()` [or in general, a library function or a system call] , its a very good idea to check for the validity of the return vale. Here you can make use of `NULL` check on the `a` variable after the `malloc()`.

Third, change the `scanf("%f", *(a+i));` to `scanf("%f", &a[i]);`.

Maybe if you write the code in following way, it should work.

```
int main() {

    int degree;
    float x;
    float px = 0;
    float p = 0;
    float *a;
    int i;

    printf("Enter the degree:");
    scanf("%d", &degree);
    printf("Enter the argument:");
    scanf("%f", &x);

    a = malloc((degree+1)*sizeof(float));

    for (i = 0; i < degree+1; i++)
    {
    printf("Enter the coefficient Nr%d:", i+1);
    scanf("%f", &a[i]);
    }   
    for (i = degree; i > -1; i--)
    {
    p = *(a+i) * pow(x, i);
    px + p;
    }

    printf("%f", px);

    return 0;
}
```